# What key metrics should I present in a technical support website report to be seen by my company's executive leadership team?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I run a monthly report which tracks session views by region, most popular knowledge articles, deflection rates, most popular product pages, software download stats, etc.

We have a new ELT member who is keen to get into the numbers around our contact centre. As I only look after the support site I need only concern myself with putting together a report which outlines what I feel will be useful information around web traffic. I want the report to be brief, and to highlight 4-5 key metrics.

Please can I have some suggestions for data you think would be useful given the target audience?

So far I am considering:

1. Deflection rates
2. Bounce rates.
3. Time on page
4. Most popular software downloads.
5. Global session views year to date.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those metrics are great. Ideally, the value in the data comes from slicing your metrics with a dimension, ie pivoting. For example,  bounce rate as an average means little whereas bounce rate by Content Group or Device Category would be more interesting.

Speaking of Device Category, consider completely isolating the metrics for Mobile vs Desktop+Tablet.  Those experiences are so drastically different you'd be doing a disservice to average those metrics together.

Lastly,  I'd say this new ETL member should get their own access to GA and learn how to pull the data need.  [GA now offers machine learning insights](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7411707) that quickly surface relevant drivers in metrics; a static approach to KPI reporting is becoming increasingly obsolete.

Comment: What a fantastic answer, you have given me something to chew on. 
 Filtering by Device Category/Content Groups is something I am going to have to look into more deeply, I can see lot's of applications.  Time on page is probably meaningless on its own. Time on an knowledge article vs time on a Contact page should be weighted differently.  Thanks!